# Adding Data to a Local OPC UA Server - Using the OPCUA Java sdk

Tags: java, server, opc-ua

I am quite new to OPCUA and currently trying to just know my way around with the help of the sample server and sample client. I have packaged the sdk for java successfully and use it in my projects pom so that I can use the UaServer and other classes. The next thing I want to do is add some dummy data to the local server that is running just to get a feel for writing data to a particular server through OPC. Loading an information model seems to be the only way as of now but I am finding that a tad bit complex.

My question is - is there an easier way to do this? Would love to hear suggestions from those who have experience in this as it is uncharted water for me at the moment :)

Comment: You don't mention which particular SDK for Java you are using. But I would recommend to study the documentation (Tutorials) and sample project that come with the SDK. Typically, you just need to add objects and variables that map your process data in the server code. Information models are more typically used for bringing in type definitions to the server, which can then help creating more complete object structures.

Comment: Yes sorry about that I am using the unified automation sdk bundle v4.6.2 for Java which can be found at [link](https://www.unified-automation.com/downloads/opc-ua-development/java-client-server-sdk-bundle.html)
I have followed along with the sample tutorials for both server and client manuals provided using the prosys sample server and client. But I still have not managed to wrap my head around how these objects and variables are added. If you could share a sample line of code on how you have implemented it, that would be quite helpful.
What ive tried is UaServer.add(some data)

Comment: Unified Automation is in practice reselling the Prosys OPC UA SDK for Java. You should look at the createAddressSpace method in MyNodeManager of the SampleConsoleServer. For further assistance, I recommend to contact Prosys support. And yes, I am involved :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice and insight Jouni, I greatly appreciate it :)